# tensorflow add new op : how to get device id in Opkernel

Tags: tensorflow

I add a new gpu kernel op(MyGpuOp), the use op in python, and specify device id by tf.device('/gpu:0' 
example :

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0') :
   out1 = my_gpu_op(input1) 
with tf.device('/gpu:1') :
   out2 = my_gpu_op(input2)
```

then i use sess.run([out1, out2], the seens won't run concurrent in different Gpu Device. beacause the run time of sess.run[out1, out2] is  twice of sess.run(out1).

in c++ op wraps(MyGpuOp), i run cuda kernel by pass steam(CudaStream_t) 
like this :

```
    //ctx is OpKernelContext 
    GPUDevice d = ctx->eigen_device<GPUDevice>();
    CudaStream_t stream = d.stream();
    MyKernelName<<<grid, block, 0, stream>>> (....);
```

Should I need get device id, then use CudaSetDevice(device_id) before run kernel fun?

Comment: Your GPU kernel should not depend on the device Id.

Comment: but why the run time of sess.run([out1, out2]) is twice of sess.run(out1) ? i want to concurrent run out1 and out2 in different gpu device , how to do it ?

Comment: This does not indicate that the two ops are not running in parallel. It is possible that each op spends more time on setting themselves up and then spend little time running. That setup might be sequential.

Comment: You should run with timeline as specified [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40410210/tensorflow-2-gpu-slower-then-single-gpu/40430717#40430717) to see if things are run in parallel. Note that example in that link shows 2-GPU version running 2x slower than 1 GPU version despite running in parallel because of setup times