# Why is my 980 TI outperforming my 1080?

Tags: performance, tensorflow, gpu, matrix-multiplication

Trying to make sure my new computer is setup properly, and noticed that its GeForce 1080 GPU is significantly underperforming the 980TI on my old system (when running Tensorflow jobs). Since the systems differ in more than just GPU, I wrote a small benchmark to isolate GPU matrix multiplication performance in TensorFlow. The results confirm that the new GPU is significantly slower. I know this is something to do with the software installed, but I've checked the obvious things: same python3, same cudnn, same numpy. What could be causing this strange performance gap?

Benchmarking Script:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import time

sess = tf.Session()
A = tf.random_uniform((1000,1000))
for i in range(int(1e3)):
        A = (tf.matmul(A,A))
cur_time = time.clock()
sess.run(A)
print(time.clock()-cur_time)
```

Old System (980 Ti):

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 980 Ti
major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.19
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 5.93GiB
Free memory: 5.39GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 980 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
time elapsed: 0.81484
```

New System (1080):

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1080
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.898
pciBusID 0000:03:00.0
Total memory: 7.92GiB
Free memory: 7.57GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:03:00.0)
time elapsed: 1.2753620000000003
```

Comment: Backticks are for inline code only. Please select multiline blocks and press the `{}` button in the editor to format them.

Comment: which driver/cuda version?

Comment: I upgraded from 980 to 1080 and saw increase in matmul speed. However, there were initial performance problems on 1080 with CUDA 7.5, which disappeared with CUDA 8.0. Also, you may want to do `sess.run(A.op)`, that only does matmul without transfer to Python client

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov thanks for the advice! Tried the A.op suggestion, but the timing was the same. Already have CADA 8.0 on both systems, so not sure what else to check. Would BLAS stuff be relevant for GPU performance?

Comment: Turns out the 1080 is significantly faster once I benchmark on larger matrices (10000x10000). Still can't figure out why the 980 would be faster on smaller matrices though (faster on all of my research projects as well). The only stat where the 980 seems superior is that it has 2 minor cores rather than the 1 in the 1080. Don't know enough about GPUs to tell if that would explain it though.

Comment: How does the time compare to no GPU at all? Also notice that there's 0.2-1 second [delay the first time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40410210/tensorflow-2-gpu-slower-then-single-gpu/40430717#40430717) you launch a kernel because of PTX compilation